# What's wrong with this bash code to replace words in files?

Tags: bash, sed

I wrote this code a few months ago and didn't touch it again. Now I picked it up to complete it. This is part of a larger script to find all files with specific extensions, find which ones have a certain word, and replace every instance of that word with another one.

In this excerpt, ARG4 is the directory it starts looking at (it keeps going recursively).
ARG2 is the word it looks for.
ARG3 is the word that replaces ARG2.

```
        ARG4="$4"
        find -P "$ARG4" -type f -name '*.h' -o -name '*.C' \
-o -name '*.cpp' -o -name "*.cc" \
-exec grep -l "$ARG2" {} \; | while read file; do
                echo "$file"
                sed -n -i -E "s/"$ARG2"/"$ARG3"/g" "$file"
        done
```

Like I said it's been a while, but I've read the code and I think it's pretty understandable. I think the problem must be in the while loop. I googled more info about "while read ---" but I didn't find much.

EDIT 2: See my answer down below for the solution.

Comment: I think get rid of all the quotes: `"s/$ARG2/$ARG3/g"`

Comment: What is not working in this code?

Comment: @theblindprophet Just did that, it still doesn't work. None of the files had their words changed.

Comment: does the the find command return any files ? Could it be possible there are no files that meet the find conditions.

Comment: @chidori there are files, I created a couple of .C and .h files and put a bunch of words in them for this purpose. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: Edited: my previous answer was incorrect, because I had commented the rest of the code to isolate the one you mentioned. When I uncommented and ran it again, it gave me an empty line and then `sed -n -i -E s/Oi/Tchau/`

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that `find` wasn't working properly. It turns out that it's because of `-maxdepth 0` which I put there so that the search would only happen in the current directory. I took it out, but then the output of `find` was one single string with all of the file names. They needed to be separate entities so that the `while` loop could read each one. So I rewrote it:

```
        files=(`find . -type f \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.C" -o \
-name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cc" \) \
-exec grep -l "$ARG1" {} \;`)
        for i in ${files[@]} ; do
                echo $i
                echo `gsed -E -i "s/$ARG1/$ARG2/g" ${i}`
        done
```

I had to install GNU sed, the regular one just wouldn't accept the file names.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say if this is the *only* issue, since you haven't said precisely what's wrong. However, your `find` command's `-exec` action is only being applied for `*.cc` files. If you want it to apply for any of those, it should look more like:

```
        ARG4="$4"
        find -P "$ARG4" -type f \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.C' \
-o -name '*.cpp' -o -name "*.cc" \) \
-exec grep -l "$ARG2" {} \; | while read file; do
                echo "$file"
                sed -n -i -E "s/"$ARG2"/"$ARG3"/g" "$file"
        done
```

Note the added `(` and `)` for grouping to attach the action to the result of all of those.

Comment: It's not working for any files. I added the escaped parentheses, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @GeleiaDeMocoto: Are you sure you want to pass `-n` to `sed`? That suppresses printing, but your `sed` code doesn't contain any explicit prints, either.  Which flavor of `sed` is this btw?

Comment: @GeleiaDeMocto Wrap your `sed` statement with `echo` to make sure the variables are expanded as expected. Then try to execute one of the echoed sed statement.

Comment: Flavor of sed? It's just standard bash sed. Since the files are being passed to the while loop, and there's an echo in there, I figured there's no need for sed to print anything.    ETA: I've added the echo. It doesn't print anything. So it's not even getting to the sed.